# Evaluate Sympy function

Tags: python, function, sympy

I found the command to evaluate a sympy function f (.subs), but it doesn't seem to work. 
In particular, I'm defining a function that depends on f, and I want to evaluate it in my function. 
The goal of this function is to compute the Gaussian quadrature given nodes and weights:

```
def Gauss_Leg(f,weights,nodes,n, P = 'Legendre'):
"""P = Legendre by default,
w = weights,
x = nodes,
n = degree of precision"""
if P == 'Legendre':
    measure = 1
    a = -1
    b = 1
integral = 0
for i in range(n):
    integral += f.subs(x, nodes[i]) * weights[i]
print('Intergation boundaries: ', a, b)
print('integral of', f, '*', measure, '= ', integral)
return

x = sym.Symbol('x', real=True) 
f = sym.exp(x)

#exact nodes and weights
[nodes,weights] = np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(n)

Gauss_Leg(f,weights,nodes,5)
```

Comment: What is your error or result?

Comment: A number multiplied for exp(x). So I tried to print f.subs(x, nodes[i]) at every loop, and it returns always exp(x): no substitution occurs.

Comment: You are reusing `x` as a variable for two different things. You need to use different variable names.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Sorry, I had already changed that. Edited.

Comment: After changing `np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(n)` to `np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(5)`, I am not getting an error. I also don't see why you need SymPy for this. You could just make a Python lambda function and evaluate it at `nodes[i]`.